# Placing the title for a table on top of table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am copying the code for a table from [an earlier post of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244786/5001) on this web site. Why is the title "Certain Function Values of 'f'" typeset to the left of the table? How do I put it on top of the table?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\textbf{16.) }\raggedright{The table shows certain function values of \textit{f}. \\If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$?}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$-5$ \\
\> \textbf{b.) }$-1$ \\
\> \textbf{c.) }0 \\
\> \textbf{d.) }2 \\
\> \textbf{e.) }4
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\belowbaseline[-7pt]{\stackunder{\bfseries\Longstack{Certain Function\cr Values of \textit{f}}{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c | S[table-format=-1.0] ||} \hline
    \textit{x}  &   {$f(x)$} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    2           &   -1 \\ \hline
    3           &   0 \\ \hline
    4           &   2 \\ \hline
    5           &   -3 \\ \hline
    6           &   4 \\ \hline
    7           &   -5 \\ \hline
    8           &   6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: f is a mathematical function? Then why are you using `\textit{f}` sometimes instead of `$f$`?

Comment: I think you should add a reference/ link of the copied/used answer. - Use: `\belowbaseline[-7pt]{\stackunder{\bfseries\Longstack{Certain Function\cr Values of \textit{f}}
}{%
\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}
}}` (Just skip 1x `}`)

Comment: Why using `stackengine` in the first place? Putting something over a table isn't that hard...

Comment: Unrelated: Your usage of `\raggedright` is wrong. This doesn't take an argument, but is delimited by `minipage` in this case.

Comment: @Mico Isn't "f" typeset the same using either `\textit{f}` or `$f$`?

Comment: @user74973 - If your document uses the default text and math font family (Computer Modern), the lowercase letter `f` will indeed look almost the same whether it's written as $f$, i.e., in math mode, or as `\textit{f}`, i.e., in italic text mode. (There's actually an important difference in the *side-bearings* of the letters. Do typeset `$f$. \textit{f}.` and also `$f(x)$ \textit{f(x)}`: can you spot some differences? ) If you ever use a font for which letters drawn using math mode and (italic) text mode are not similar, the difference will be more obvious. Notational consistency is important.

Comment: @user74973 - By the way, in my earlier comment, I deliberately wrote that `$f$` and `\textit{f}` "look almost the same". Under high magnification, one can indeed spot some non-trivial differences. E.g., run the following LaTeX program: `\documentclass[border=0.4pt]{standalone} \usepackage{color} \begin{document} \textit{f}\kern-6.075pt\color{red}$f$\kern-2pt\color{black}$f$\kern-5.085pt\color{red}\textit{f}\end{document}`. (This superimposes the letters in two ways.) You should be able to spot differences in the lengths of the cross-bars and the shapes and sizes of the terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need stackengine for this: here is  solution with a single tabular, usinng the `\thead` command from `makecell`, and some improvements with `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\textbf{16.) }\raggedright{The table shows certain function values of \textit{f}. \\If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$?}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$-5$ \\
\> \textbf{b.) }$-1$ \\
\> \textbf{c.) }0 \\
\> \textbf{d.) }2 \\
\> \textbf{e.) }4
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{|| c | S[table-format=-1.0] ||}
 \noalign{\vspace*{-2.65ex}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\clap{\thead{ Certain Function\\ Values of $ f $}}}\\
 \hline
 \textit{x} & {$f(x)$} \\ \hhline{||--||} \hhline{||--||}
 2 & -1 \\ \hhline{||--||}
 3 & 0 \\ \hhline{||--||}
 2 & -1 \\ \hhline{||--||}
 4 & 2 \\ \hhline{||--||}
 5 & -3 \\ \hhline{||--||}
 6 & 4 \\ \hhline{||--||}
 7 & -5 \\ \hhline{||--||}
 8 & 6 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic variant of putting the description on top of the table using another `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\raggedright
\textbf{16.) }The table shows certain function values of $f$. \\If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*.)}]
  \item $-5$
  \item $-1$
  \item $0$
  \item $2$
  \item $4$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \bfseries Certain function\\
  \bfseries Values of $\boldsymbol{f}$\\[.5em]
  \begin{tabular}{ c  S[table-format=-1.0] }
    \toprule
    $x$  &   {$f(x)$} \\
    \midrule
    2    &   -1 \\
    3    &   0 \\
    4    &   2 \\
    5    &   -3 \\
    6    &   4 \\
    7    &   -5 \\
    8    &   6 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
%}}}

\end{document}
```

I used `booktabs` to make the table look much better, imho. Also I used `enumitem` for the enumeration instead of `tabbing`.

[image]

Comment: @Mico thanks. Didn't spot that one (who uses `\hline` in the same line as `\begin{tabular}`?) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses two side-by-side, top-aligned `minipage` environments. (I've borrowed (stolen?!) the idea to use a custom `enumerate` environment instead of a `tabbing` environment from [@Skillmon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417070/5001).) Observe that by honing the details of the layout, it's **no longer necessary to use a lot of boldfacing** to provide visual clarity.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,enumitem}
\newlength\mylen  % see below for use of this length parameter

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\raggedright
\textbf{16.)} The table on the right shows certain 
function values of~$f$. If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what 
is the value of~$g(2)$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)\ ]
  \item $-5$
  \item $-1$
  \item $\phantom{-}0$
  \item $\phantom{-}2$
  \item $\phantom{-}4$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{\fill}% maximize the horizontal separation
%% Calculate width of 2nd minipage:
\settowidth\mylen{Certain function}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\mylen}
\centering
Certain function values of $f$

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} c S[table-format=-1.0] @{}}
\toprule
    $x$  &   {$f(x)$} \\
\midrule
    2    &   -1 \\
    3    &    0 \\
    4    &    2 \\
    5    &   -3 \\
    6    &    4 \\
    7    &   -5 \\
    8    &    6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```